# AngualrJS route not working when updating param value directly in URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here below is my URL

`localhost:9000/index.html#!/app/apis/1066/general`.

If I change value of `param` to 1067 it should update `API(s)` general information based on 1067. 
But instead `URL` is set back to `param` value 1066 instantly and the page is not refreshed. 
Here is my route:

```
     $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        debug:false,
        events:true
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/welcome');

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract:true,
            url:'/app',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html'
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })

        .state('app.api', {
            url: '/apis',
            controller: 'apiCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/apis/index.html'
        })

        .state('app.addApi', {
            url: '/apis/add',
            controller: 'apiCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/apis/createApi.html'
        })
            .state('app.apis', {
            url: "/apis/:id",
            templateUrl:"views/dashboard/apisMain/updateApis.html",
            controller: "updateApisCtrl",
            resolve:{
                apiData :function ($stateParams,  proxyService) {
                    return proxyService.api($stateParams.id);
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.apis.general', {
            url: "/general",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard/general/updateGeneral.html",
            controller: "updateGeneralCtrl"
        })
```

I can provide more information if needed. I'm using angularjs 1.7

Answer (score 0):

It might be so that the stateprovider does not consider new url props in it's cache-key.
Try to disable the cache on the state and see if it helps

```
.state('app.apis', {
    cache: false,
    url: "/apis/:id",
    templateUrl:"views/dashboard/apisMain/updateApis.html",
    controller: "updateApisCtrl",
    resolve:{
        apiData :function ($stateParams,  proxyService) {
            return proxyService.api($stateParams.id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss param ID in path config state general,  Please try change it:

```html
state('app.apis.general', {
            url: "/general",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard/general/updateGeneral.html",
            controller: "updateGeneralCtrl"
        })

>>>change  

state('app.apis.general', {
            url: "/:id/general",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard/general/updateGeneral.html",
            controller: "updateGeneralCtrl"
        })
```